Should Euler be credited with Prime Number Theorem?
Shouldn't Euler, rather than Gauss, be credited with the intuition that $\pi(n)\sim n/\log n$ since he stated that $\sum _{p} \frac{1}{p}=\log \log \infty,$ (which implies the PNT) since it is considered that he meant that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes less than $n$ is asymptotic to $\log \log n$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

Euler never came across anything like the prime number theorem, and moreover he once said "Mathematicians have tried in vain to this day to discover some order in the sequence of prime numbers, and we have reason to believe that it is a mystery into which the human mind will never penetrate". That appeared as the 1st sentence of the paper https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/175/

Since you suggested incorrectly that an estimate written without proof by Euler and first proved by Mertens might imply the prime number theorem, you'll be interested to read https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95743/why-could-mertens-not-prove-the-prime-number-theorem.

The statement $\sum_{p\le x} \frac1p \sim \log\log x$, which was proved by Mertens, is strictly weaker than the prime number theorem (in the sense that we can replace the set of primes by other sets of integers for which the sum of the reciprocals is asymptotic to $\log\log x$ yet the counting function of the set is not asymptotic to $x/\log x$).

Do you have an example, or an argument to show one exists?

Take for instance a random set of integers where $n$ is “prime” with probability $(1+\sin(\log n))/\log n$.

That's really interesting, thanks

Consider $A(x) = \sum\limits_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p}$. Then the Abel summation formula gives $$\pi(x) = x A(x) -\int_2^x A(t) \, dt$$
At this point one can't use $A(x) \sim \log\log x$ to approximate the integral, but with the stronger approximation $A(x) = \log\log x + \mathcal O(1)$ we have
$$\pi(x)=x(\log\log x + \mathcal O(1)) -\int_2^x (\log\log t + \mathcal O(1)) \, dt = x\log\log x + \mathcal O(x) - \left(x \log\log x - 2\log\log 2  - \mathrm{Li}(x)+\mathcal O(x)\right) = \mathrm{Li}(x)+\mathcal O(x)=\mathcal O(x)$$
$\mathrm{Li}(x)$ is the correct term for $\pi(x)$, but the error term is bigger, so the approximation turns out to be trivial.
If you use the even stronger approximation $A(x)=\log\log x + C + \mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)$ you'll get $\pi(x) = \mathcal O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$ which is better but still not equivalent to the PNT.
